# Rotation Method Called many Times

Tags: ios, swift

Why below method called many times?

```
application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?)
```

Here is my example code:

https://github.com/wgywgy/RotationScreenDemo

Comment: Please add _relevant_ code to your question. DO NOT post links to your repo.

Answer (score 0):

> This method returns the default interface orientations for the app.
>   These orientations are used only for view controllers that do not
>   specify their own.

This method is called for each `viewController` you present to define with orientation to use.